# AzureCliCredential giving error, Please run 'az login' to set up account

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, azure-managed-identity, azureclicredential

I am using `ChainedTokenCredential` and trying to get managed identity token in local debug environment using `Visual Studio 2019`. In windows terminal I already logged in using `Azure CLI` `az login`.

```
var credential = new ChainedTokenCredential(
                    new ManagedIdentityCredential(),
                                new AzureCliCredential());

var token = await credential .GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { _configuration.GetSection("scope").Value }));
```

When I am running code in debug I am seeing below error,

> The ChainedTokenCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
> ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. No Managed Identity endpoint found.
> Please run 'az login' to set up account

Where I need to do `az login`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute `az logout` first and try again `az login` and I suggest to set default subscription by executing `az account set -s "Subscription ID"`

Comment: Install Azure Cli (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) and execute  suggested commands in Command Prompt (Windows)/ Terminal (Linux)